# Which one is correct? Including, Includes, or Its including?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

1. The agreement has yet to be formulated, but including crucial points which must be worded carefully
2. The agreement has yet to be formulated, but its including crucial points which must be worded carefully ?
3. The agreement has yet to be formulated, but includes crucial points which must be worded carefully ?

Comment: Is there any more context? None of these are a complete sentence.

Comment: Those are not even full sentences.

Comment: The agreement has yet to be formulated, but ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can cut out some of the parallel structure and consider only the relevant parts of the sentence

You should consider which is a correct and complete sentence.

1. The agreement including critical points.
2. The agreement its including critical points.
3. The agreement includes critical points.

Only one of these has a finite verb, and a finite verb cannot be a gerund or participle.

So only the third sentence can possibly be correct.

For good measure, you might try

4. The agreement is including critical points.

But this is wrong, since the present continuous doesn't work here (use simple present for simple facts such as whether a document includes something or not.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help